# Strange behavior when Looping through Files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

This is driving us crazy, this should work!

When ran (Stepping)

It jumps over the debug.print (No Errors)

Then it hits i += 1

Never stops at the next (break point)

But i=51 !

Any Clues

```
If CheckBox8.Checked = False Then
        Exit Function
    Else
        Dim fInfo As FileInfo()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim dInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(spath.ToString)
        fInfo = dInfo.GetFiles("*.xml")
        Dim sfiles As String()
        Dim sFile As String
        sfiles = Directory.GetFiles(spath, "*.xml")
        For Each sFile In sfiles
            Try
                Debug.Print(sFile.ToString)
                i += 1
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print(ex.Message)
            End Try

        Next


    End If
```

Comment: is this because you not building it in *DEBUG* configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to work correctly

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim spath As String
        spath = "C:\YOUR_DIRECTORY"

        Dim fInfo As FileInfo()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim dInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(spath.ToString)
        Try
            fInfo = dInfo.GetFiles("*.xml")
            For Each fi In dInfo.GetFiles("*.xml")
                Dim file_name As String
                file_name = fi.Name
                Console.WriteLine(file_name)
                i = i + 1
            Next
            Console.WriteLine("Found:" + i.ToString + " Files")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

Note: Debug.Print will print to the **"Output Window"** in Visual Studio, Not the command line, so..... the Debug.Print statements might not be entirely obvious if you dont have the output window open.

[image: Degug.Print in VBA]

Comment: Debug.Print(sFile.ToString)
Have both Immediate and Output Windows Open